# dcast With multiple Ids and variables

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

I want to "un-melt" a data.frame that has multiple IDs and multiple melted variables and I'm stuck.

This is what my dataframe looks like:

[image]

This is the desirable outcome

[image]

I have tried:

```
unmelted <- dcast(setDT(melted), Id, Date, Type ~  Score, Time, 
                                value.var = c("Score","Time"), sep = "")
```

And

```
unmelted <- melted %>%
   group_by(Id, Date, Type) %>%
   unite(variable, Score, Time)%>%
   spread(Score, Time, -Id, Date, Type)
```

I cannot use `pivot_wider`.

Comment: **Don't post pictures of your data!** You should provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `tidyverse` solution, using `gather` and `spread` from `tidyr` pacakge:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) #version 1.0.0 which has pivot_wider

df1 %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  mutate(name_x = row_number()) %>% 
  gather(key=var, value=val, c(Score, Time)) %>% 
  mutate(var = paste(var, name_x, sep="_")) %>% 
  select(-name_x) %>% 
  spread(key=var, value=val)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 11
#> # Groups:   Type [3]
#>      id Date  Type  Score_1 Score_2 Score_3 Score_4 Time_1 Time_2 Time_3 Time_4
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1     1 2001~ aaa       123     456     789      NA 12:12  13:12  14:12  <NA>  
#> 2     2 2001~ ddd       113     145      NA      NA 15:12  16:12  <NA>   <NA>  
#> 3     3 2001~ bbb       789     145     113     145 17:12  18:12  19:12  20:12
```

You can do the same with `pivot_wider` much more conveniently:

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  mutate(name_x = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("id","Date", "Type"), 
              names_from = c("name_x"), 
              values_from = c("Score", "Time"))
```

***Data:***

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                  Date = c(rep("2001-01-13", 3), rep("2001-01-16", 2), rep("2001-01-18", 4)),
                  Type = c(rep("aaa",3), rep("ddd", 2), rep("bbb",4)),
                  Score = c(123,456,789,113,145,789,145,113,145),
                  Time = paste0(12:20, ":12"),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I have a question. The result was as expected but I got this error. Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables;
they will be dropped. Could anyone explain what that exactly means?

Comment: @DanielleTravassos That's not an error. It's a warning saying that number of variables for each group (`key`) are not the same. It works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), id + Date + Type ~ rowid(id, Date, Type),
     value.var = c("Score","Time"), sep = "")
#   id       Date Type Score1 Score2 Score3 Score4 Time1 Time2 Time3 Time4
#1:  1 2001-01-13  aaa    123    456    789     NA 12:12 13:12 14:12  <NA>
#2:  2 2001-01-16  ddd    113    145     NA     NA 15:12 16:12  <NA>  <NA>
#3:  3 2001-01-18  bbb    789    145    113    145 17:12 18:12 19:12 20:12
```

Using data  from @M--

Comment: Hi akrun, Thank you for your reply. I keep getting this error that I was getting before: Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
In if (!(value.var %in% names(data))) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used. Do you know what it means, by any chance?

Comment: @DanielleTravassos  My testing was based on the example in the M--'s post.  If your column names are different, you may need to change accordingly

Comment: Hi Akrun, Yes, with his data, I'm getting this message.

Comment: @DanielleTravassos  Sorry, not reprroducign it with `R 3.6.2` and `packageVersion('data.table')#
[1] ‘1.12.8’`